# receiving ssl certificate via certbot, nginx in docker-composer

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, certbot

I have docker compose project and there are some services: nginx, certbot and php-fpm.
It works well but i want to make little devOPS optimization.

That is my docker-compose.yml file (part of it) which describe certbot container:

```
certbot:
        image: certbot/certbot
        container_name: certbot
        volumes: 
            - ./docker/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt/
            - ./docker/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot/
        command: certonly --webroot -w /var/www/certbot/ --email mail@gmail.com -d admin.xxx.ru -d catalog1.xxx.ru --agree-tos --cert-name xxx
        networks:
            - app-network
```

```
That is nginx.conf which attached to my docker-compose.yml (reverse proxy, but here only first few lines are important):
```

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/privkey.pem;
        client_max_body_size 500M;
        server_name admin.xxx.ru www.admin.xxx.ru;
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-admin;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/certbot;
        }
    }
```

```
The problem is that everytime when i want to retrieve SSL certificate, I have to change my nginx configuration:
server listen only 80 port, lines 'ssl_certificate' have to be commented. 
After that I use docker-compose up, container which contains certbot
create SSL, and falls. And after that I have to edit one more time nginx configuration to listen 443 and get proper ssl_cerificate.
It works but I suppose it can be done easier.

This step is neccessary just because with nginx configuration like shown before docker server will not start and it will not receive proper SSL certificate (nginx container will fall).
What the ways to make it simplier? Perhaps there is way to create other server block which will be for SSL certificate receiving, or something tricky with docker-compose.yml?
Thanks.
```

I tried to create bash script, which will do all these actions, but it was very unconvinient.